# master branch not showing all the files after I merged another branch into master

Tags: git, github, git-merge

So, I merged my another branch `redux` into master, and expected to work properly. But looks like some files are missing in the master branch. I just did this:

from `redux`:
`git checkout master`
`git merge redux`

and it showed 6092 additions, 755 deletions. I think the deletions were the files deleted that I'm not seeing in the master.

In the terminal, it shows like:

```
localhost@localhost:~/Desktop/myApp$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  origin/redux
```

**on master**

```
localhost@localhost:~/Desktop/myApp$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 27 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

**on redux**

```
localhost@localhost:~/Desktop/myApp$ git status
On branch redux
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/redux'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Also, on github, when I switch to redux branch, it shows.
[image]

---

I'm toally confused, I was supposed to merge redux into master and went totally wrong.

`This branch is 28 commits ahead, 2 commits behind master.`. What does it mean?

All I want is to make the master branch look exactly like redux branch. What should I do? Should I create a new branch from `redux`, work on it, and merge it into master?

Comment: Note that it's often *not* a good idea to make one branch look exactly the same as some other branch, because that means *give up all the work someone did on this one branch*. Merging, in Git, is about *combining work*, which keeps it, rather than throwing the work out.

Comment: Since "work done" is represented, in Git, as "new commit snapshot", merging simply adds another commit, just as committing does. So if you were 27 ahead, and you add a merge, you can expect to be 28 ahead now.

Comment: Presumably, you are now "2 behind" because someone else added 2 new commits to their master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, when you created the branch, both branches where on the same commit.

The fact it's saying your `redux` branch is 28 commits ahead and 2 commits behind `master`, means that after the creation someone made 2 new commits on master and pushed them.
These 2 commits still can be merged on your `redux` branch, or if you prefer, you can take care of it when merging the `redux` branch`into`master` (some conflicts could happen).

Same logic applies to the 28 commits ahead: you pushed 28 commits on the `redux` branch since its creation.

The reason you are not able to see some files on `master` after merge, it's because those files have been deleted on the `redux` branch.

Last but not least, do not confuse your local repository with the origin.

What you see on github is the `origin/master` which can be ahead or behind your local master branch.

I'd suggest you to use the `compare` button on github to have a simple visual understanding of the branches differences.
This can also be achieved via command line using git, but a GUI can help a lot when you're still learning.

Push your changes on your origin via

`git push origin master`

Comment: On redux branch. I clicked the compare button and it showed that files such as Header, Footer, and many more have been deleted. But I can see all of the files on my repo, in redux branch. How?

Comment: when you clone a repository you make a copy. When you push to your repository, you update the remote repository with your local modification.
It seems you're having trouble understanding this.
When you commit something on your repository, it will not update your remote repository!

Comment: So, you mean I have to push to master after merge?. I think I did not do that.

Comment: you need to push anything if you want to see it on github.
you can also check via git the difference between the local and the remote branch
`git diff redux..origin/redux`

Comment: on master it gives `On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 27 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
`

wow, i missed that. i think i need to do git push origin master.

Comment: yeah, i just realized i gave you a lot of explaination but didn't wrote the obvious command.

Comment: yes i did that and the changes are there. Now, On redux it shows `This branch is 2 commits ahead, 3 commits behind master.`. The two commits are changes I made in Readme.md. So should i delete the branch?

Comment: yes, if you don't need it anymore remove it locally `git branch -D redux` and then delete the remote `git push origin :redux`

Comment: thanks, mate. I really appreciate your time in helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

If your branch is *X behind master* then to following (there are many different ways):

```
git checkout master (you are switching to master branch)
git pull (integrates the latest version from the current (master) branch)
git checkout redux (switch back to your branch redux)
git merge master (conflicts could arise)
```

If the conflicts could be resolved, then push the redux branch only with:

`git push`

then both branches have the same status.

Comment: But the latest changes are on `redux`.

Comment: on master it gives `On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 27 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
`

wow, i missed that. i think i need to do git push origin master.